# Stop code running when user deselects div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, this, setinterval

I'm trying to stop the setInterval function from running when the user deselects the div that they selected but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?`

I've tried the clear interval and that's not working. I've also tried using the cvalue from *this* but it doesn't update within the code.

```
 $(document).on("click",".profTemp", function()
                { 
                  var pollUser;
                  if(!$(this).hasClass('selected'))
                  {
                    var selectedUser;
                    var previous = null;
                    var current = null;
                    var assigned = false;

                    selectedUser = $(this).children('span').text();
                    selectedUser = selectedUser.trim();



                    //selectedUser = $(this).children('span').text();
                    console.log(selectedUser);
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

                    //selectedUser = selectedUser.trim();

                    pollUser = setInterval(function()
                    {

                      console.log(selectedUser);
                      $.ajax({
                        url: '/getJSON',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response) {
                          console.log(response + "84897348");
                          obj = JSON.parse(response);
                          console.log(selectedUser + "inside success");

                          var changeTo;
                          var deviceID;

                          console.log(current + "current");
                            for(var i = 0; i < obj.clients.length; i++)
                            {
                              if((selectedUser == obj.clients[i].userName) && (assigned == false))
                              {
                                console.log(selectedUser + " inside if");
                                current = JSON.stringify(obj.clients[i]);
                                changeTo = obj.clients[i].uri;
                                device = obj.clients[i].deviceID
                                assigned = true;
                              }
                            }
                            assigned = false;

                            console.log(current + " current");
                            console.log(previous + "previous");

                            if(previous !== current)
                            {          

                              console.log("ARE WE INSIDE HERE");

                              $.ajax({
                                url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play',
                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                type: 'PUT',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                headers: {
                                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                                },
                                data: JSON.stringify({"uris":[changeTo], "device_id":device, "offset": { "uri":changeTo} }),
                                success: function(response) {
                                  console.log(response);
                                }
                              });
                            }
                          }
                        });
                      previous = current;
                      console.log(selectedUser);
                    }, 2000);
                  }

                  else if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
                  {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                    console.log("not selected");
                    clearInterval(pollUser);
                  }       

                });
```

`

Comment: Is "not selected" logging to the console?

Comment: yep, it logs and then just goes back and loops over the code in pollUser

Comment: Oh, one second typing up answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var pollUser` is where you expect the id of the setInterval to be, correct? Because later in the function, you do `pollUser = setInterval(function()...` . See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) on setInterval.

This isn't working because on every `click` of `.profTemp`, you are creating a new `pollUser` variable by doing `var pollUser` at the top of your function.

If you want the ID of your setInterval to actually save, you should save it to a variable outside the scope of the `.profTemp` click handler function, so it is maintained.

[Some more resources on function scope](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

and on ["var"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score -1):

Put var pollUser;  before onclick function.

Comment: komali_2 explained why :D